# Syncing Solr indexes to Hadoop-friendly format

Tags: hadoop, solr

I want to do recommendation, clustering and classification on our data currently stored in Solr. Solr is our **primary** data store. I am just getting started with Mahout + Hadoop for this.

I assume that a Solr index is not a friendly format for input to Mahout (or other Hadoop jobs); and I must convert it to a textual format before I can perform map-reduce operations on it. That is, I must have a text file in HDFS that is **always synchronized** with data in Solr.

What is a good plan to use data in Solr for Hadoop/Mahout? Should I sync changes in Solr to a file in HDFS?

---

Heres how I plan to sync solr data to a file. For user `X`:

1. fetch 100 documents since LATEST_TIME
2. convert these documents to text and store with filename: 'X_LATEST_TIMESTAMP'
3. merge X_LATEST_TIMESTAMP with master file: if master text file says doc ID 123 has content and X_LATEST_TIMESTAMP says that that document is deleted, the new master file reflects that change
4. update LATEST_TIME

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off looking at something like [DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise), which includes and integrates (AFAIK) Solr, Cassandra, and Hadoop. Of course, it is a commercial offering. They have a community edition, but I don't think it integrates Solr.